# URLs metadata in docpad returning 404

Tags: docpad

I'm migrating off one blogging platform to DocPad and part of this migration I'm planning on improving my URL format on my website, but obviously I don't want to break my existing SEO and external links so I want to have some way that the old URLs will still work, just result in a redirect.

I was directed to the [`urls` metadata property](http://docpad.org/docs/meta-data) but it doesn't seem to be working for the old URL, here's my metadata header:

```
--- cson
title: "Some blog post title"
date: "2013-05-07"
tags: ["tag1"]
urls: ["legacy-url"]
summary: """

"""
---
```

This can be then accessed via the url:

```
/posts/2013-05-01-some-blog-post
```

But I need it to be accessible via the old url of:

```
/legacy-url
```

So what seems to be amiss with the metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work locally with `docpad run`? If you are deploying to a static server, you'll want to install the cleanurls plugin that will create the necessary redirect pages for you. This is because the redirects happen with the docpad node.js web server unless you are using the cleanurls plugin in conjunction.